# Running a command-line command in terminal using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, terminal

I have to basically run a terminal-command using python script. General way of doing this would be

```
In [1]: import subprocess

In [2]: subprocess.Popen(['python some-python-script.py'],shell=True)
Out[2]: <subprocess.Popen at 0x103425358>
```

Now, my requirement is that this script will be triggered n (<=10) times printing some output. How do i ensure that everytime its triggered using python, it opens in *new* terminal tab printing the output?

Checked couple of refernce online and tried using

```
In [11]: os.system("Terminal -x python some-python-script.py")
sh: Terminal: command not found
```

but doesn't help.

I am on OSx Sierra but a platform independent solution is welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) from the **subprocess** module. As your command must be executed more than once, you can just call the function inside `for` loop. The script may look something like this (the upper bound of the `range` may be variable):

```
import subprocess

for idx in range(5):
    print(subprocess.check_output(['python3', 'full-path-to-script.py'], encoding='utf-8'))
```

As mentioned in the documentation, the `check_output` function returns the data as encoded bytes, but as the encoding is specified in my example, the output will be UTF-8 encoding string. Depending on your command the decoding to text may need to be handled separately.